# Can't stop MobyLinuxVM when docker is not needed?

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v

Running docker on Windows 10 using Hyper-V.

When I stop the MobyLinuxVM from the Hyper-V manager, docker stops working. At this point, I can still get response to commands like 'docker -v' but every other command fails. For example: 'docker ps' returns an unknown command error on Windows Powershell. Docker did not start to work normally even after changing the state of MobyLinuxVM to running from the Hyper-V manager. The only way I could get docker to work normally again was uninstalling-reinstalling it.

My question is: Will the MobyLinuxVM always keep on running in my system and eating resources even if I do not need to use docker at a given moment? (There's an assigned memory of 2048 MB even if CPU utilization is zero). Is there some way of stopping the MobyLinuxVM, then restarting it when I need to work with docker and have docker work fine?

Is there a way to start and stop docker at will?

Comment: Did you try stopping docker? It sits in the system tray and is preconfigured to run on windows startup by default.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vivek says, just stop Docker in tray.